# Connect to RHEL SAMBA share without username/password on Windows

Tags: rhel, samba

I have our smb.conf set up as below

```
# See smb.conf.example for a more detailed config file or
# read the smb.conf manpage.
# Run 'testparm' to verify the config is correct after
# you modified it.

[global]
    workgroup = SAMBA
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

    guest account = samba

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes
    create mask = 0600
    browseable = No

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
    write list = @printadmin root
    force group = @printadmin
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775

[edi]
    path = /dat/101/edi/
    public = yes
    create mask = 0664
    directory mask = 0775
```

I want Windows users to be able to open `\\server\edi` without being prompted to enter a username and password. I have tried mixture of options from browsable, public, force user, force group etc. with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried making them part of the same domain?

Comment: Access them how -- as unauthenticated guests or as authenticated users?

Comment: As guests. I just want anyone on the network to be able to open `\\server\edi` without the Windows username/password prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You need `guest ok = yes` and `guest only = yes` on each service definition.

From the man page:

> **guest only (S)**
>
> If this parameter is yes for a service, then only guest connections to the service are permitted. This parameter will have no effect if guest ok is not set for the service.
>
> See the section below on security for more information about this option.
>
> Default: *guest only* = no

Note that either or both of these can be in the `[global]` section instead of the service definition.  Also `public` is a synonym for `guest ok` and `only guest` is a synonym for `guest only`.

Answer (score -1):

add "guest ok = yes" to your share definition. Also check folder rights.

To recheck your configuration log out and in on your windows client, that the connection is closed.

Also your should know, that your have to add the authenticated user to your guest share (when you have them), because windows only use one authentication session.